# After upgrade from API 28 to 33 My app crashes almost on all device emulators

Tags: firebase, crash, upgrade, pid

I am able to login and fetch the previous data into my app. But when I fill up the register form on my app the data is updated to the Firebase Database. But when I try to login into the app with that information. the app crashes with below error :

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.commercial.rututechnologies.societymanagement, PID: 1799
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
at com.commercial.rututechnologies.societymanagement.activities.AdminActivity$2$1.onDataChange(AdminActivity.java:162)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
2023-08-16 11:50:37.028  1799-1799  Process                 com...echnologies.societymanagement  I  Sending signal. PID: 1799 SIG: 9

I tried to check if there are any issues with the Firebase database plugins, but I see they all are uptodate.

My expectation would be, the app should not crash after logging into it using the newly registered account.